# definition of CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION and CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server

If other (scalar and table) functions I can find in syscomments and stored procedures in sys.procedures, where I can find body of **CLR**_SCALAR_FUNCTION and **CLR**_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION?

Thanks

Comment: CLR code is NOT stored in the database. It is compiled to a dll and then moved into a custom assembly.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to programatically get and use CREATE FUNCTION .... to recreate same function in another db for ie?

Comment: No. You need to have the compiled dll. Then you can create an assembly in your other database.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was SQL, not CLR. Yeah, for the definition of a CLR function (the actual C# code), you'll need to have source code (or at least the DLL). The actual code is not inside SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, no problem and you should keep your answer because it was very helpfull expecially OBJECT_DEFINITION ( object_id )  function that "Returns the Transact-SQL source text of the definition of a specified object". Thank you

Comment: But it didn't answer *this* question.